# How to use mix-blend-mode to change text color on an animated background

Tags: css, frontend, mix-blend-mode

I have a codepen with 4 boxes,

each box has a text on top of a moving background svg. I am using mix-blend-mode to invert the colors of the text when the background changes. For example, if the background is red, the text should be yellow, if the background is yellow, the text should be red.

My problem:

1. It seems like the technique is not working with chrome
2. It seems like the technique is not working with hex colors. Am i missing a point, or is this a bug?

Working codepen: https://codepen.io/nicopoggenburg/pen/xxmaeGw

[image: Left side chrome, right side firefox]

Mac Firefox: No, Mac Chrome: No

```
.box-1 {
  --light: #FCFAF0;
  --dark: #082605;
}
```

Mac Firefox: **Yes**, Mac Chrome: No

```
.box-2 {
  --light: yellow;
  --dark: red;
}
```

Mac Firefox: No, Mac Chrome: No

```
.box-3 {
  --light: #66CDAA;
  --dark: #FFA500;
}
```

Mac Firefox: **Yes**, Mac Chrome: No

```
.box-4 {
  --light: green;
  --dark: purple;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="box box-1">
  <div class="svgs">
    <div class="svg-container">
      <svg class="svg svg-1" viewBox="0 0 1024 244" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M1029 59.77c-258.25 0-258.25 124.62-516.5 124.62S254.25 59.77-4 59.77" stroke="#082605" stroke-width="118.634" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
      </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="svg-container">
      <svg class="svg svg-2" viewBox="0 0 1024 244" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M1029 59.77c-258.25 0-258.25 124.62-516.5 124.62S254.25 59.77-4 59.77" stroke="#082605" stroke-width="118.634" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h1 class="text" data-text="Do reinvent the wheel">Do reinvent<br>the wheel</h1>
</div>

<div class="box box-2">
  <div class="svgs">
    <div class="svg-container">
      <svg class="svg svg-1" viewBox="0 0 1024 244" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M1029 59.77c-258.25 0-258.25 124.62-516.5 124.62S254.25 59.77-4 59.77" stroke="red" stroke-width="118.634" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
      </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="svg-container">
      <svg class="svg svg-2" viewBox="0 0 1024 244" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M1029 59.77c-258.25 0-258.25 124.62-516.5 124.62S254.25 59.77-4 59.77" stroke="red" stroke-width="118.634" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h1 class="text" data-text="Do reinvent the wheel">Do reinvent<br>the wheel</h1>
</div>

<div class="box box-3">
  <div class="svgs">
    <div class="svg-container">
      <svg class="svg svg-1" viewBox="0 0 1024 244" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M1029 59.77c-258.25 0-258.25 124.62-516.5 124.62S254.25 59.77-4 59.77" stroke="#FFA500" stroke-width="118.634" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
      </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="svg-container">
      <svg class="svg svg-2" viewBox="0 0 1024 244" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M1029 59.77c-258.25 0-258.25 124.62-516.5 124.62S254.25 59.77-4 59.77" stroke="#FFA500" stroke-width="118.634" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h1 class="text" data-text="Do reinvent the wheel">Do reinvent<br>the wheel</h1>
</div>

<div class="box box-4">
  <div class="svgs">
    <div class="svg-container">
      <svg class="svg svg-1" viewBox="0 0 1024 244" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M1029 59.77c-258.25 0-258.25 124.62-516.5 124.62S254.25 59.77-4 59.77" stroke="purple" stroke-width="118.634" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
      </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="svg-container">
      <svg class="svg svg-2" viewBox="0 0 1024 244" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M1029 59.77c-258.25 0-258.25 124.62-516.5 124.62S254.25 59.77-4 59.77" stroke="purple" stroke-width="118.634" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h1 class="text" data-text="Do reinvent the wheel">Do reinvent<br>the wheel</h1>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@keyframes moveWave {
  to {
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
}


.box-1 {
  --light: #FCFAF0;
  --dark: #082605;
}
.box-2 {
  --light: yellow;
  --dark: red;
}
.box-3 {
  --light: #66CDAA;
  --dark: #FFA500;
}
.box-4 {
  --light: green;
  --dark: purple;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: var(--light);
  color: var(--light);
  padding: 20px 0;
  isolation: isolate;
}
.svgs {
  display: flex;
  width: 200%;
  animation: moveWave 5s linear infinite;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.svg-container {
  width: 100%;
}
.svg {
  width: 100%;
}
.text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 90px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  font-weight: 800;
  width: fit-content;
  color: var(--dark);
}

.text:after {
  content: attr(data-text);
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  color: var(--light);
}
```

Comment: Your pen is showing red text on yellow background and vice versa - i.e. problem solved. Please edit the question to show what the problem actually is.

Comment: Initial post is now up to date with the problem.

Answer (score 2):

It is necessary to once again display the text with the second color (for example, using `.text:after`) and apply `mix-blend-mode: difference;`:

```css
@keyframes moveWave {
  to {
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
}

:root {
  --light: yellow;
  --dark: red;
}
.box {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: var(--light);
  color: var(--light);
  padding: 20px 0;
}
.svgs {
  display: flex;
  width: 200%;
  animation: moveWave 5s linear infinite;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.svg-container {
  width: 100%;
}
.svg {
  width: 100%;
}
.text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 90px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 0;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  font-weight: 800;
  width: fit-content;
  color: var(--dark);
}

.text:after {
  content: attr(data-text);
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  color: var(--light);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="svgs">
    <div class="svg-container">
      <svg class="svg svg-1" viewBox="0 0 1024 244" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M1029 59.77c-258.25 0-258.25 124.62-516.5 124.62S254.25 59.77-4 59.77" stroke="red" stroke-width="118.634" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
      </svg>
    </div>
    <div class="svg-container">
      <svg class="svg svg-2" viewBox="0 0 1024 244" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
        <path d="M1029 59.77c-258.25 0-258.25 124.62-516.5 124.62S254.25 59.77-4 59.77" stroke="red" stroke-width="118.634" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
  <h1 class="text" data-text="Do reinvent the wheel">Do reinvent<br>the wheel</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution! Do you know why this works with colors like red, yellow, green and purple but not with custom colors? I have extended my [pen](https://codepen.io/nicopoggenburg/pen/xxmjmNQ) with other examples.